# I am having issues with a button app where audio is supposed to be played when I click a button in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

Here is the output of my xml code:

[image]

Here is the output of my Main activity file:

[image]

Here is the logcat info for my app:

> 3-25 05:19:17.503 11521-11521/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni     (already on)
>       03-25 05:19:17.595 11521-11521/com.example.pentazoid.buttonaudio W/System:   ClassLoader referenced unknown path:   /data/app/com.example.pentazoid.buttonaudio-1/lib/x86
>       03-25 05:19:17.673 11521-11521/com.example.pentazoid.buttonaudio  D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
>       03-25 05:19:17.736 11521-11521/com.example.pentazoid.buttonaudio D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>       03-25 05:19:17.737 11521-11521/com.example.pentazoid.buttonaudio   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                           Process: com.example.pentazoid.buttonaudio, PID: 11521
>                                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.pentazoid.buttonaudio/com.example.pentazoid.buttonaudi o.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual  method 'void  android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on  a null object reference
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                          at com.example.pentazoid.buttonaudio.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>   03-25 05:20:05.622 11521-11527/com.example.pentazoid.buttonaudio W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.919ms

What am I doing wrong

Comment: find the button id after setting the contentview.And change the button id to findViewById(R.id.button).

Comment: You should implement method zero

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that in you xml you are namde button id `button`, and in your java file you want to get `findViewById(R.id.buttonId)` just change to `findViewById(R.id.button)` and also move `setContentview` in start in method `onCreate` before your `button` some like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

and last problem:

and remove the `android:onClick` in your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

move contentView above then findViewById and replace R.id.buttonId with R.id.button

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

Replace the xml like:

```
android:id="@+id/button"
```

and remove the android:onClick

and in your MainActivity do this:

```
Button zero = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
zero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do anything
            }
});
```

and of course put it after setContentView.
Hope it helps!!!

Comment: this is not solve his problem ... did you see where he declare his contentView.... app will crash when is started

Comment: this is why i mention put it after setContentView

Answer (score 0):

if you show us `activity_main.xml` would be easier to find,

make sure did you include content_main.xml.

make sure `R.id.buttonId` placed in which `XML` file ?

your order should be like the following:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       Button zero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);

}
```